# Karate way of accessing a value in JSON object with number string as property (key)

Tags: testing, automation, karate

I'm having a JSON response from an API as per below:

```
{
  "lanes": [
    {
      "laneId": "6ef9deb2-de6d-43f7-baed-fe00de3a11d4",
      "name": "LaneTest",
      "dayShifts": {
        "1": [
          "Morning Shift"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "laneId": "559165e9-d675-4537-99e7-a0f3b73de3c8",
      "name": "testaaa",
      "dayShifts": {
        "1": [
          "11am shift",
          "5:00 pm shift"
        ]
      }
    }]
}
```

Based on the response, I'm trying to find a lane object which contains the value "Morning Shift" under the `dayShift.1` array and below is my attempt:

```
 * def shiftFilter = function(x) { return x == 'Morning Shift' }
 * def laneIdFilter = function(x) { return karate.filter(x.dayShifts.1, shiftFilter) }
 * def laneObj = karate.filter(response.lanes, laneIdFilter)
```

Upon executing the above code, I'm getting the following error:

```
>>> failed features:
js failed:
>>>>
01: (function(x) { return karate.filter(x.dayShifts.1, shiftFilter) })
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:47 Expected , but found .1
(function(x) { return karate.filter(x.dayShifts.1, shiftFilter) })
                                               ^
Unnamed:1:65 Expected ; but found )
(function(x) { return karate.filter(x.dayShifts.1, shiftFilter) })
                                                                 ^
Unnamed:1:66 Expected } but found eof
(function(x) { return karate.filter(x.dayShifts.1, shiftFilter) })
                                                                  ^
 - org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:425)
 - com.intuit.karate.graal.JsEngine.evalForValue(JsEngine.java:139)
 - com.intuit.karate.graal.JsEngine.eval(JsEngine.java:135)
 - com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.evalJs(ScenarioEngine.java:1190)
 - com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.evalKarateExpression(ScenarioEngine.java:2143)
 - com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.evalKarateExpression(ScenarioEngine.java:2062)
 - com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.evalAndCastTo(ScenarioEngine.java:1251)
```

However, when I attempt to filter based on other properties of the lane object (i.e: name), it works correctly. It seems that Karate is unhappy with the usage of `1` in the `dayShifts` object.

I'm new to Karate and I would really appreciate if someone can shed some lights on this.

Karate version: v1.3.0

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is `1` is interpreted as a number, so you need to use the alternate way of referring to JSON using keys in square-brackets - which is: `x.dayShifts['1']`

I'm giving you a more concise solution, the latest version of Karate has JS  "baked in" so normal [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) operations work:

```
* def lane = response.lanes.find(x => x.dayShifts['1'][0] == 'Morning Shift')
```