# Empty variable translated to empty array rather than empty string

Tags: karate

When making a background call, I capture numerous variables and they show as string values or empty.  However, when I print out the variable in my scenario, it returns as an empty array **"firstDMAPIRouterId": [***<line break in here>***]**, rather than an empty string **"firstDMAPIRouterId":***""*.
[image]

I tried casting the variable in the background call as a string rather than def, but that returns a similar, but different, issue of a string with empty array brackets without the line break.
[image]

How can I extract a value from a previous call and not have it cast as an array, when empty?

added image showing the result of json pretty print
[image]

results using print concatenation
[image]
results using print comma separation
[image]

small sample

```
Feature:
Background:
    * def jsonExample =
"""
    {
        menu: {
            id: 'file',
            value: 'File',
            popup: {
                menuitem: [
                    {value: 'New', onclick: 'CreateNewDoc()'},
                    {value: 'Open', onclick: 'OpenDoc()'},
                    {value: 'Close', onclick: 'CloseDoc()'}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
"""

Scenario:
    * print jsonExample
    * def newItem = get[0] jsonExample.menu.popup.menuitem[?(@.value == 'New')].onclick
    * print 'onclick value of new is:  ', newItem
    * def saveItem = get[0] jsonExample.menu.popup.menuitem[?(@.value == 'Save')].onclick
    * print 'onclick value of save is:  ', saveItem 
    * string saveItem2 = get[0] jsonExample.menu.popup.menuitem[?(@.value == 'Save')].onclick
    * print 'onclick value of save2 is:  ', saveItem2       
    * def saveItem3 = karate.jsonPath(jsonExample, "$.menu.popup.menuitem[?(@.value == 'Save')].onclick")
    * print 'onclick value of save3 is:  ', saveItem3
```

results of empty array

```
13:40:43.394 [com.intuit.karate.cli.Main.main()] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] onclick value of new is:   CreateNewDoc() 
13:40:43.397 [com.intuit.karate.cli.Main.main()] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] onclick value of save is:   [
]
 
13:40:43.400 [com.intuit.karate.cli.Main.main()] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] onclick value of save2 is:   [] 
13:40:43.432 [com.intuit.karate.cli.Main.main()] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] onclick value of save3 is:   [
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If Karate prints an empty array, it simply means that it *is* an empty array. In Karate `null`, `''` and `[]` are completely different.

EDIT: To "filter" out JSON "pieces" out of a given JSON, my recommendation is to use JS functions instead of JsonPath. JsonPath always returns an array, so if nothing was "found" it returns an empty array. Perhaps that was the source of confusion.

Here is how I would approach the JSON provided in your question:

```
Feature:

Background:
* def jsonExample =
"""
    {
        menu: {
            id: 'file',
            value: 'File',
            popup: {
                menuitem: [
                    {value: 'New', onclick: 'CreateNewDoc()'},
                    {value: 'Open', onclick: 'OpenDoc()'},
                    {value: 'Close', onclick: 'CloseDoc()'}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
"""

Scenario:
    * print jsonExample
    * def newItem = jsonExample.menu.popup.menuitem.find(x => x.value == 'New')
    * match newItem.onclick == 'CreateNewDoc()'
    * def getMenuItem = x => jsonExample.menu.popup.menuitem.find(y => y.value == x)
    * def openMenuItem = getMenuItem('Open')
    * match openMenuItem.onclick == 'OpenDoc()'
    * def saveMenuItem = getMenuItem('Save')
    * match saveMenuItem == null
```

Note that `getMenuItem` above is a JS function. It is the short-form of this:

```
* def getMenuItem = function(x){ return jsonExample.menu.popup.menuitem.find(y => y.value == x) }
```

And for more explanation, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75484078/143475 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/72691069/143475

Comment: I understand different response types, but that was not my question.  Since I am extracting a string, as shown in the routerId fields, why would this field return as an empty array rather than an empty string, when an object is not found.  If the extraction of a json should always return arrays, why is the routerId field not wrapped in array tags?  Additionally, the array is not empty as it contains a line break as shown in the first screenshot.

Comment: @mike I honestly don't understand what you mean by `extracting a string`. karate "pretty prints" JSON, hence the line-feed

Comment: @mike I'm pretty sure your call has failed or is not doing what you expect. can you confirm that if you have a 2 line karate test, where line 1 does a `def` of some JSON and line 2 prints some part of the JSON, that it works correctly ? please ? also, string concatenation is NOT recommended for `print`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#print

Comment: Changed to , separation and see the pretty print difference, but this does not explain why an empty variable, not found in original response json, is set as an empty array rather than an empty string

Comment: @mike I don't understand the sentence above at all. here is an example where a) I have a so-called empty variable, and b) after a response comes back, c) nothing happens to `emptyVar`, it continues to be an empty string : https://github.com/ptrthomas/karate-test/blob/main/src/test/java/examples/test/empty-response.feature

Comment: From my understanding of json, I could be wrong so please correct me if I am, is that Valid minimal JSON strings are:  
The empty object '{}', 
The empty array '[]', 
The string that is empty '""', 
A number e.g. '123.4', 
The boolean value true 'true', 
The boolean value false 'false', 
The null value 'null'.  
So if a field is not found, why is an empty array returned rather than a null as it is unclear if the field in question is a string, array, or object?

Comment: @mike for JSON, I suggest you spend a few minutes with someone who knows JS and that will be most effective. but `""` is not valid JSON. just a number on its own is not valid JSON. the primitives can appear within JSON, e.g. `{ someKey: true }` etc. again I am completely lost when you say `field is not found`. what is a field here ? a karate variable ? a part of some other JSON ? it would be much easier to work off an example.

Comment: By field not found, I am referring to the field not being present in the json object being evaluated.

by '""' being invalid, the single quotes were used to surround the result, and not a part of the result itself, such that '[]' is actually []

Comment: @mike is it possible for you to create a single snippet of a  *simple* `Scenario` that shows what you mean by `being evaluated` and `the result` and `field`, thanks. ideally not more than 2 or 3 lines should be sufficient

Comment: added sample in original post

Comment: Sounds like this is an issue in more than just Karate, as many languages have issues handling [] versus a null or empty object.  https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T12887